# Basic troubleshooting, Function onclick will not work

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Practice with condition statements.</title>
            <script LANGUAGE="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction()
            {
            if (document.getElementById(input1).value == John);
                    {
                        alert("This is correct!");
                    }
            else
                    }
                        alert("This is incorrect!");
                    }
            }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body bgcolor="green">
            Answer:<input type="text" name="answer" id="input1">
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this function will not display alert messages. I've messed with it for at least an hour and a half and it is giving me a headache. I hope this isn't some easy fix that has been eluding my eyes. I am very new at this so please be gentle with any criticism. :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input1` is **not** a variable or object, You must wrap it in **"doublequotes"** or **'singlequotes'**. Use:

```
document.getElementById("input1").value
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById(input1).value
```

Comment: I guess that wasn't the bug I am experiencing. Maybe I should state my problem from a different angle. What I am trying to do is practice checking text that is inputted into a text box using a button. For instance with the page above, their should be a text box for people to put in text, and the button would check whether or not what they inputted is correct or not. My problem is that when I click the button nothing happens. No alert messages pop up or anything. So my new question would be "Is there a bug that I am missing or does this require different coding altogether?".

Comment: If you use Google Chrome, right click on your page and select Inspect Element, then click on Console tab. Then try click on your button there should be errors popping up.

Comment: JavaScript, by default any string without quotes is considered variable or object. In your script, the getElementById is using the value of variable input1 which is null; and the statement will never be true because John is not defined either. Please, Use quotes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment on my code. I appreciate your answers. I have another question, how would I go about defining what strings to look for. Again, your answers are very appreciated.

Comment: Define the answer by:

var answer = "Dinosaurs";

Check:

if (document.getElementById("input1").value == answer)

If the user puts in Dinosaurs, the statement will be true.